# Error with UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been trying to write an image on a layer using Quartz but all I see is totally empty images... this is the code

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect backRect  = CGRectMake (0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

CGLayerRef backLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext (context, image.size, NULL);
CGContextRef backContext = CGLayerGetContext (backLayer);

CGContextDrawImage(backContext, backRect, image.CGImage);
```

can you guys please tell me what is wrong with this code?

image is a UIImage taken with the camera.

Yes, the image is there. If I replace the above code with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);  
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

I see the image. But I have to have it in a layer, as it is a sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really doing anything with the layer you created. You should add it to the current context using CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint() or CGContextDrawLayerInRect() or ...

You could add the following:

```
CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, backRect, backLayer);
```

or

```
CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context,CGPointZero,backLayer);
```

Comment: what about the line CGContextDrawImage(backContext, backRect, image.CGImage);? Isn't it drawing the layer on the context?

Comment: No, you're drawing the image ON the new layer you created, but the layer itself should be added to the current context.

Comment: ah, OK. I have added the line  CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointMake(0,0), backLayer); at the end of the code but I am still getting empty images... all my hair is becoming gray in despair...

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that a CGLayer is different than a CALayer.  A CALayer is what can be animated around by Core Animation, where a CGLayer is just a convenience for pulling together a static 2-D Core Graphics drawing.  Because you are referring to this as a sprite, I'm assuming you'll want to animate this around, so CALayer would be the better choice.

I recommend reading the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), particularly the [section on providing layer content](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006642).  CALayers will give you very good performance when it comes to animation, because they are GPU-accelerated and don't need to be redrawn every frame.  Core Graphics will not give you anywhere near acceptable performance for animation, because redraws are expensive operations.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure that the images were found in the right place?
- Is the image format and color numbers supported by this iphone?
- The images are not overdrawn by other drawing calls?
- In the worst case an undetected memory leak caused the images to be overwritten in memory

Comment: everything is there. If I precede this code with the lines 

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);  
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];  

the image is drawn correctly.